# How does the entropy of $r$ influence the security of the one-time pad $F_k(r) \oplus m$?

Tags: one-time-pad, pseudo-random-function, entropy

In an one-time pad scheme, $s \oplus m$ is uniformly random for any $m \in \{ 0,1 \}^\ell$ if $s$ is uniform in $\{ 0,1 \}^\ell$. By the security of PRF, it seems to be secure to replace the truly uniform string $s$ with the output $F_k(r)$ of a PRF $F: \{ 0,1 \}^\kappa \times \{ 0,1 \}^\ell \rightarrow \{ 0,1 \}^\ell$. Let us consider a case where $r$ can only be chosen from ***a small range with limited entropy*** (e.g., $\{ 0...00,0...01 \}$ with $\ell - 1$ leading zeros). Is it possible for an adversary ***who has no idea about $k$*** to distinguish between the one-time pad $F_k(r) \oplus m$ and a truly random string? If possible, how does the entropy of $r$ influence the advantage of such an adversary?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Keep in mind that, when you saying it seems to be secure, actually, you are switching from perfect secrecy to computationally bounded adversary model, in which, we want the adversaries gain is negligible.

Comment: @kelalaka, thanks for your comment. Indeed, in this case, I am interested in the computational indistinguishability between $F_k(r) \oplus m$ and a truly random string.

Comment: Hint: what happens if $r$ repeats in several experiments using the same $k$?

Comment: How many samples does the adversary get to see?